# How to set a value to reference field in service now epic or user story using rest api

Tags: c#, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I need to set a value in service now user story type for epic or parent (any reference) field using create or update request of REST API in c#. I have tried setting the link and the value to the epic field to JSON object using c# class.

```
storyObj.epic.link="https://<companyname>.service-now.com/api/now/table/rm_epic/{sys_id}";    storyObj.epic.value= "{sys_id}";
```

The user story is getting created with blank epic or parent field.
The epic is declared like this in my class-

```
 public Epic epic { get; set; } public class Epic
{
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
 }
```

but when i am setting the value its coming like this-

`"epic": {
        "link": "https://company.service-now.com/api/now/table/rm_epic/{value=d385c54adbb5bb00f493894d0",
        "value": "{value=d385c54adbb5bb00f493894d0"
      },`

Comment: That should be correct. Make sure you have the correct sysId of the epic and maybe try without setting the link.

Comment: ya but still its not working

Comment: Looks like you need to do something like this: ``storyObj.epic.value= "{sys_id.value}";``

Comment: no this will not work in c#. as  sys_id is defined as  `public string sys_id { get; set; }`

Comment: So then you parsed the sysId incorrectly in the first place? ```sys_id = responseFromRest.sysId.value```

Comment: Actually that's not the case, I resolved the issue by myself.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the c# object format (for json coversion) to all string properties.

```
public string epic { get; set; }  
public string parent { get; set; }
public string shadow { get; set; }
public string watch_list { get; set; }
public string phase_type { get; set; } 
...............
```

and then for post or put request to servicenow I am passing additional parameter to return json response in all string.

```
HttpClient httpClient = ContectToServiceNow();
var content = new StringContent(json.ToString(), UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, 
"application/json");
response = httpClient.PostAsync("api/now/table/" + tableName + "? 
sysparm_exclude_reference_link=true", content).Result;
```

so now while updating the sys_id i can directly assign the sys_id from service now to any reference field, like 
    `epic = sys_id;`